# How to position 3 stacked bar graphs using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I'm trying t create a graphic with three stacked bar graphics, like so:

[image]

I actually have two questions:

1) I'm trying to use the 'position' parameter in Pandas' DataFrame, but the bars still overlap. Is there another alternative other than reducing the width of the bars?

2) The three bars have three categories in common (B, C, D, E), how can I have a legend that only contains the actual six different categories ?

My DataFrame is:

```
          A         B         C         D         E         F
0  0.108858  0.265929  0.537369  2.183963  1.353575  2.938775
1  0.375641  0.198720  0.266806  0.409179  0.286645  0.636405
2  1.179256  0.808986  0.171202  0.946194  0.506783  2.121366
3  1.510399  1.218619  0.307752  0.819865  1.283067  0.213556
```

And my test code is:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(abs(np.random.randn(4, 6)), columns=list('ABCDEF'))

print(df)

colors1 = ['#a50f15', '#9ecae1', '#6baed6', '#3182bd']
colors2 = ['#fb6a4a', '#9ecae1', '#6baed6', '#3182bd']
colors3 = ['#fcbba1', '#9ecae1', '#6baed6', '#3182bd']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))

df.plot(ax=ax, y=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], kind='bar', stacked=True, width=0.15, color=colors1, position=0)
df.plot(ax=ax, y=['E', 'B', 'C', 'D'], kind='bar', stacked=True, width=0.15, color=colors2, position=0.5)
df.plot(ax=ax, y=['F', 'B', 'C', 'D'], kind='bar', stacked=True, width=0.15, color=colors3, position=1)

ax.legend(ncol=3)

plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Comment: for your second question you can do the following : `ax.legend(ncol=3, labels=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'])`

Comment: Does changing the position parameter to -0.5, 0.5, 1.5 get what you want?

Comment: Actually it does, thank you!! I never tried negative values as the documentation states: "position : float Specify relative alignments for bar plot layout. From 0 (left/bottom-end) to 1 (right/top-end). Default is 0.5 (center)"

@HamzaHaider

Partially. The last label color is not right:
[new image](https://imgur.com/a/2FogIKi)